# SimpleITK: Iterate the label list

Tags: java, binding, itk

I'm trying to iterate the label list of a SimpleITQ image (generated from the morphological watershed filter), but I can't figure out how to do it. 
I know the `LabelImageToLabelMapFilter` class can be helpful, but it seems not to be available in the **java** binding..

Do you know how to accomplish this?

Comment: I am not sure what you mean by iterate offer the labels. Do you want a list of label IDs? Is there some type of data you want the label id to be mapped to like a set of pixels or statistics about that label?

Comment: I need to get a list containing the label position (position of the pixels) and eventually an ID. Then I will compute some parameters like the histogram of the label on the original RGB image or the mean color of the pixels. Unfortunatly I think there is no way to compute these parameters on the original image because ITK uses grayscale images.. but it's another problem.